# Mount a windows network folder for all users using cifs with fstab

Tags: mount, permissions, fstab, shared-folders, cifs

I'm following this tutorial https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently to always have mounted windows network folder in the ubuntu server machine

My entry in the `fstab` is:

```
//192.168.2.177/SharedFolder /mnt/localpath cifs rw,credentials=/var/credentials.txt,users 0 0
```

When I'm using root I can read/write in the `/mnt/localpath` folder, but for other local users I just have read-only access. What did I miss? How can I give write permissions for all users in the Ubuntu machine?

Comment: Please try with: `//192.168.2.177/SharedFolder /mnt/localpath cifs rw,credentials=/var/credentials.txt,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8,x-gvfs-show 0 0`

Comment: It didn't work out  @SpasSpasov `ls: cannot open directory .: Permission denied`. Not even read-only access